# Center multiple divs on wrapping

Tags: css

I have a container with multiple divs (more than 2):

```
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  ...
</div>
```

And I want to center these divs (one div in every line) when screen size is too small to fit all. How can I implement this using pure CSS3?

Comment: Provide your current CSS please.

Comment: I have already provided at the beginning of the post. The parent element is `container`, and it's children `div`s should be centered when screen size is too small.

Comment: HTML is not CSS

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Flexbox.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code will only be applied when the screen width is smaller that: 400px, feel free to change the value the way you want.

Comment: I should center children when the overall width of children is more than screen size, and not when screen size is less than some specific width.

Comment: @programmer well then you'll need JavaScript to do that, CSS won't calculate the width of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Modern centering method using flex, this is all you need for centering anything:

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

And you can apply `flex-direction` to make the element inside flex container align horizontal or vertical. So the result look like below:

```css
.container {
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container div {
  margin: 10px;
  width:60vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) { 
  .container {
    flex-direction: column
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I need to center children when screen size is too small to fit them all. When screen size is big enough, they should be located one by one.

Comment: I think you need to take a look at media query, when a screen size reduced to a certain width you need apply `flex-direction: column`, when the screen is big, apply `flex-direction:row`

Comment: Edited to add media query

Comment: Take a look at the comment I left on the previous answer. Do you know option that allows me not to use JavaScript as @Tarek said?

Comment: Im afraid it is impossible to do so with css right now, with CSS you can manually do that by checking screen size, calculating the element width and apply it on certain width with media query

Answer (score 0):

This would center the div but when the multiple div can be fit in a line, it would make inconsistency in the number of div's in each line.

```css
.container{
  text-align: center;
}
.container div{
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to center these divs (one in every line) and not to make their width 100%.

Comment: Is the width of each div fixed?